# Fire autocmd FileType on current buffers in windows

Tags: vimrc, autocmd

#### Context

I have shortcuts to edit my `vimrc` and to source my `vimrc`.  When I'm writing code I can quickly add a new mapping and then source `vimrc`.  And all that would be good if I did not use `autocmd FileType` for most of my mappings.

Since most mappings are specific to one file type I keep my `vimrc` in a form similar to this:

```
function! FtPython()
  setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 autoindent
  nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>c I#<esc>

  " Let's say that this is a new mapping
  nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>cc ^wC:<esc><left>i

endfunction

if has("autocmd")
  augroup filetype_vimrc
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python call FtPython()
    ...
endif
```

Yet, when I add a new mapping to `FtPython()` and source my `vimrc`, the new mapping is not present in the `python` buffers because the `FileType` event happened long ago, when the file was read.

When I read a buffer back into a window `FileType` will be fired and the mapping will be added, but that does not happen when a window is already open and I just move into it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>).  In essence, once I add a new mapping all **currently open windows** need to be "kicked" to get the new mapping.

I work around it by doing (I force the `FileType` event to fire):

```
set ft=python
```

But that is quite a lot of typing, sometimes I have 2-3 `python` files in different windows (`split/vsplit`) and I need to do it for each.  `argdo` is not an option since it will close the windows (as far as I know).

---

#### Question

Is there a good way to fire the `FileType` event on all windows that Vim is currently showing?

Or, maybe, is there a better way to structure the mappings?

Comment: (1) `autocmd FileType` has its uses, but local setting are much better left to `ftplugin` files: then it's Vim's task to apply them at the right moment, not yours. (2) Contrary to the popular belief, `vimrc` is not really meant to be sourced multiple times. You can do it, but it takes a lot of careful backwards bending to avoid pitfalls. (3) How about `bufdo` for updating options.

Comment: @SatoKatsura `:bufdo` is a good idea.  I missed the part about different files.

Comment: Btw. Some `set` commands works with `:windo` instead (when you've multiple files in split mode).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a good way to fire the FileType event on all windows that Vim is currently showing?

Use `:e` instead of `:set ft=python` to reset the current buffer.  It re-reads the file and triggers the relevant autocmds for the buffer.

Update: I missed the part about different files.  You could re-set the filetype for all buffers with `:bufdo`

```
:bufdo doautocmd FileType
```

alternatively:

```
:bufdo let &ft=&ft
```

There is also `doautoall` which can re-trigger the `FileType` autocmd in all buffers:

```
:doautoall FileType
```

The methods above are a bit heavy handed and not without drawbacks.  If you want to affect only `python` filetypes:

```
:bufdo if &ft == 'python' | doautocmd FileType | endif
```

as a command that accepts the filetype as an argument:

```
command! -complete=filetype -nargs=1 FiletypeReload bufdo if &ft =~# '\<<args>\>' | doautocmd FileType | endif
```

> Or, maybe, is there a better way to structure the mappings?

You could use filetype scripts in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`.  Then you wouldn't need to source `vimrc` to pick up the changes. The methods above will cause the ftplugin scripts to be sourced for you.  Since it's sourced *after* other filetype scripts, it will also guarantee that the mapped keys are actually yours and not something a plugin introduced.

If you're using this method, you can change the command above to use the `filetypeplugin` group:

```
command! -complete=filetype -nargs=1 FiletypeReload bufdo if &ft =~# '\<<args>\>' | doautocmd filetypeplugin FileType | endif
```

The `filetypeplugin` group is used to trigger only the `FileType` autocmd in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin.vim` which is responsible for running `ftplugin` scripts.  This would be preferred since the outcome is slightly more predictable than triggering `FileType` autocmds setup at runtime.

Comment: Wow, awesome answer!  Actually I used `python` files as an example since it is the most common situation for me.  But I just tested with two python files and one JS file and both `bufdo` and `doautoall` reload the `autocmd`s (for all files) nicely.  I need to admit I'm a little afraid of meddling with the `ftpplugin` (someday i'll get there).

Comment: @grochmal `ftplugin` scripts are simply loaded when the `filetype` is set.  What's nice about them is that they aren't loaded when they aren't needed and you can have script-local variables and functions. You can read about how they're loaded with `:h vimfiles`. There's a link to my dotfiles in my profile if you want to see how I'm using them.

Comment: @TommyA ```:bufdo if &ft == 'python' | doautocmd FileType | endif``` doesn't work... I am on Vim 8.2. It opens up an empty buffer with no ```&ft``` being an empty string in the current buffer